# Is every puck used in a game given to a player?

Tags: ice-hockey

I'm used to see the puck used to score a goal be given to the player that scored the goal; but this seems to be something else. https://twitter.com/TomasPleky14/status/1103306786965278721

Carey Price got what I would guess is the puck that was used in the last seconds of play for his 314th victory.

So it sparks the question: Is every single puck used in a game given to a player playing the game? Or are those photos just for big events (Tie of a record, hat tricks, first goal, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pucks are often only for show and sometimes sold or [auctioned](https://auctions.nhl.com/iSynApp/allAuction.action?sid=1100803&rc=20&selectedCatId=16040&sort=timeleft_asc&pgmode1=catpage&navid=auctions-nav-Game-Used%20Pucks) later. Some players keep them, some don't.

During a game about 10-15 pucks (or even more) are used and not all of them are given away to players. Some will be kept or given to fans and unusable/damaged pucks get discarded.